# How can I extract a value from a list of dictionaries?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a dictionary:

```
dict = {
       "Bolig":[
          {
             "Internal_id":27698,
             "Title":"Thorshammer 95 7500 Holstebro",
             "Area":87.0,
             "Rent":6295.0,
             "Room":4
          }
       ],
       "Contact":[
          {
             "Name":"John Doe",
             "Email":"doe@gmail.com",
             "Phone":"33751010212"
          }
       ]
    }
```

I want to extract the value of one of the keys : For example the value of the `Internal_id` key gives me the value 27698. 
I tried to combine the dictionaries to a single `dict` by:

```
new_dict = {key: value for r in dict for key,value in r.iteritems()}
```

and extract but I got an error:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'iteritems'
```

Is there a way I could achieve this?

Comment: What is the expected output for this?

Comment: The value of a key. For example for the key() 'Title'. The value is returned which is 'Thorshammer 95 7500 Holstebro'

Comment: So what you want is to merge the inner dictionaries into a single one?

Answer (score 2):

`for r in dict` will iterate over the *keys* of the dictionary: `"Bolig"` and `"Contact"`. So, `r` will be a string, and strings don't have the `iteritems` method (nor do dictionaries in Python 3 - you should be using `items` instead).

You should iterate over the stitched together *values* of `dict`:

```
import itertools

stitched_values = itertools.chain.from_iterable(dict.values())
result = {key: value for r in stitched_values for key, value in r.items()}
```

Or, if each value of the dictionary is guaranteed to be a list of *one* element:

```
result = {key: value for r in dict.values() for key, value in r[0].items()}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the dictionary comprehension

```
{key: value for r in dict for key,value in r.iteritems()}
```

`r` is the keys of `dict`, which in your case are strings. You can change this to

```
{key: value for r in dict.values() for key,value in r[0].items()}
```

Answer (score 1):

We need to target each layer one by one, the first is a dictionary so we use the key to target the nested dictionaries and in this case that is "Bolig" or "Contact". Then we use [ ] brackets to access the list and pass in an index. Then finally we target the attribute inside the innermost dictionary.

Now that we know how to access each dictionary and list you can understand how to automate this using loops.

```
x = dict['Bolig'][0]['Internal_id']

print(x) # 27698
```